# How do I capture sound on Windows XP with ffmpeg?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, audio, ffmpeg, capture

I'd like to capture the stereomix or line-in sound on Windows with the Windows build of ffmpeg. On linux I'd do something like this:

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -ac 2 -ar 48000 -i front rec.flac
```

This records from the alsa device, and saves it as FLAC. Now, I'd like the same thing, but on Windows.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, no one came up with this, really, so this is what I use most of the time:

I use [sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/).

It is the best option so far, I can record with `rec`, it will always record from the activated device in the windows sound configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about ffmpeg specifically, but

Here's something to try..which has worked for other programs like audacity or sndrec32.

just generally tells windows to record what would come out the speakers before it comes out. Instead of taking input from the mic or line in. This has then worked when hitting record in programs.

Open the volume control(start..run..sndvol32, or the icon in the tray), then go to options..properties..recording..then check boxes stereo mix and mono mix. Now choose Stereo mix or mono mix.

Then if I recall, when you open start..run..sndrec32.exe  if you play things and hit record it should pick it up. Instead of things from the mic again when you want it.

And remember to change it back so you get recording from mic again!

It worked for the few programs i've used.. So it may help for ffmpeg too.

Comment: OK, but what should I chose for `-i` and `-f` options then?

Comment: I don't know. I searched for recording from line in or mic and didn't find things, then searched for ffmpeg windows record from, and I found this  http://ffmpeg-users.933282.n4.nabble.com/Capturing-webcam-video-in-windows-using-FFMPEG-td937443.html   it's from the ffmpeg users mailing list.. it says By running: 
ffmpeg -f vfwcap -i 0 output.mpg 
you should be able to record from the default device. 

You might have to pass the framerate before the -i, such as: 
ffmpeg -f vfwcap -r 25 -i 0 output.mpg   I haven't tried it though

Comment: Erm, I don't plan to capture video. VfW is is just a format filter for re-encoding. A friend of mine looked through the source code of FFmpeg and confirmed, that it's simply not possible to capture sound with FFmpeg. VfW is for input devices, like Webcams, capture devices, etc.

Answer (score 0):

With the recently added directshow support, you should be able to capture it by selecting stereo mix in your “recording properties” 
and then recording with the "normal" audio line in.

You could use a directshow audio "sniffer" if you're on vista/windows 7 https://github.com/rdp/virtual-audio-capture-grabber-device

then it's

$ ffmpeg -f dshow -i audio=virtual-audio-capturer out.mp3

Comment: I settled on using SOX recorder for that. It works reasonably well.

Comment: so sox can record stereo mix?

Comment: yes, it can. If stereo mix is selected in the volume/sound manager, sox will record from that pseudo device.

Comment: ok yeah, that option will only work if you sound card "exposes" stereo mix, if not available then other options might then be necessary for some users.

Comment: It is driver dependent. The standard audio drivers of Windows do that, though. Back in the Windows XP days, it was pretty much the fallback for any recording, as this is the downmix before it goes off to the line-out/speaker DACs. You pretty much only run into problems, when you have some fancy sound card that uses its own highly specialized drivers. Even ASIO devices work with that.